# Link Combobox and datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, combobox

I have a comboBox which is filled using this query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(LogTime, 0, 12) AS Expr1
 FROM   SSISLog
```

I have a datagrid which contains 5 columns

```
Name , ID , Event ID , EventType , LogTime
```

I have a function which I have used on other comboboxes so that when an item is picked the datagrid then goes to this item simply using

```
      private void comboBox9_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     }
```

But this time it's not working as the datasources are different , can anyone show me how to do this ?

Comment: Can you post your requirement ..little more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to find a 'selection changed' event for a `DataGrid`, please take a look at the [WPF datagrid selected row clicked event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120616/wpf-datagrid-selected-row-clicked-event) post here at StackOverflow. In short, you can attach a handler to the `DataGridRow.Selected` event:

```
<DataGrid ... >
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Row_DoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

From the linked post.