# How to programmatically add a double-click event to a WPF DataGrid Row?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I can see based on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3120866/181771 that it's possible to add a double-click event to a DataGrid row, e.g.:

```
<DataGrid ... >
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Row_DoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Is it possible for me to do this in C#, depending on certain conditions? If so, how?

Comment: Check out UIElement.AddHadnler(). Add the handler to the entire grid and then check e.OriginalSource in the event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
myRow.MouseDoubleClick += new RoutedEventHandler(Row_DoubleClick);
```

Comment: Not exactly sure but adding it at a row level could be challenging (int terms of both perf and coding effort) as it'll require post processing for each Db change - I'd suggest to handle it at a DataGrid level and then filter it by OriginalSource type, that's what routed events are designed for aren't they?