# WPF DataGrid row double click event programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to programmatically create a DataGrid and need to add a double click row event to it.  How is this done in C#?  I found this;

```
myRow.MouseDoubleClick += new RoutedEventHandler(Row_DoubleClick);
```

Although this does not work for me since I am binding the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to a collection and not manually adding in the rows.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easiest to subscribe to `myGrid.MouseDoubleClick` and then in the event handler check if the click happened on a row (or which row is selected)?

Comment: Unless by "programmatically create a DataGrid" (which, btw, taken literally, means there would be no DataGrid Element in the XAML File), you just mean "binding the DataGrid.ItemsSource to a collection and not manually adding in the rows", which I suspect is what you meant esp. based on you marking Rohit Vats's A on "Apr 1 '14 at 16:37" as the Accepted A, this Q is a dupe of  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120616/wpf-datagrid-selected-row-clicked-event".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF datagrid selected row clicked event ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120616/wpf-datagrid-selected-row-clicked-event)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can do that in XAML by adding **default style for DataGridRow under its resources section and declare event setter** over there:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Row_DoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

**OR**

In case want to do it in code behind. Set `x:Name` on grid, create style programatically and set the style as RowStyle.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"/>
```

and in code behind:

```
Style rowStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
rowStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(DataGridRow.MouseDoubleClickEvent,
                         new MouseButtonEventHandler(Row_DoubleClick)));
dataGrid.RowStyle = rowStyle;
```

**AND**

There is example of event handler:

```
  private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
     DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;
     // Some operations with this row
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will retry.

Comment: Thanks!! If somebody needs this code for **PowerShell** copy this code: https://gist.github.com/PatrickGrub/94841e76b4ba45beb28a4fab94c29120

Comment: This only answers the "add a double click row event to it" part of the OP's Q (unless of course, by "programmatically create a DataGrid", he just means "binding the DataGrid.ItemsSource to a collection and not manually adding in the rows, which I suspect is what he meant).".  I'm just saying, that literally speaking, "programmatically create a DataGrid" means there would be no `DataGrid` Element in the XAML File.

Comment: Just as note, sender is a DataGrid, not a row. You may use DataGrid.SelectedIndex or any other accessor to manage the action on your handler