# Checking a CheckBox in a DataGrid when double clicking on the corresponding row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a DataGrid with 3 Text columns and one CheckBox column :

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="EquipmentArray" Style="{StaticResource DataGridEquipment}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP Adress" Binding="{Binding IPAdress}"/>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Connection Type" Binding="{Binding ConnectionType}"/>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Choice">
             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                       <CheckBox/>
                  </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGridColumns>
</DataGrid>
```

I would like to make it so that when the user double clicks on a row, it checks the CheckBox in the according row.

```cs
private void DataGridRow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        // checking the checkbox in the sender's row
    }
}
```

How could I do this and what would be the best way?

Comment: maybe a duplicate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790181/wpf-datagrid-row-double-click-event-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a boolean property like `IsEnabled` to your data model and bind it to the `CheckBox`:

**DataItem.cs**

```
class DataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // Let property raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event
  public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDoubleClick"
                   Handler="OnDataGridRowPreviewMouseDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>

  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Choice">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGridColumns>
</DataGrid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void OnDataGridRowPreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  var row = sender as DataGridRow;
  (row.Item as DataItem).IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: My `Description`, `IPAdress` and `ConnectionType` being in an `Equipment` model, should I add the property `IsEnabled` to that model and implement the interface or create a new class like you did?

Comment: My class `DataItem` was just an example. You have to add this property to your existing data model that makes your rows and serves as the binding source for your columns. Also notice how the example handles the `PreviewMouseDoubleClick` event instead of counting mouse clicks.

Comment: So my existing data model now has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this to work?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise the binding won't update to reflect changes.

Comment: [PropertyChanged example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-6.0)