# How to return record from datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, datagrid

I work with wpf, and I have a datagrid which lists all my clients from the table client.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="liste_clients" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Uid="liste_clients" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" SelectionChanged="client_select">
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=nom}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="NOM" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=prenom}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="PRENOM" Width="*">
</DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

this my function

```
private void client_select(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            linqDataContext dataContext = new linqDataContext();
            client client = (client)liste_clients.SelectedItem;
            int id = client.id;
            MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
        }
```

I just want to click on a row, and get the corresponding object in my function.
I don't know how to do it.

And I still have a client referenced null.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120616/wpf-datagrid-selected-row-clicked-event

Comment: if you have selectedItem as not null , you might want to cast it like "liste_clients.SelectedItem as client "