# How to tell which row of DataGrid was clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which is filled with a List of Objects.
It has a `MouseDoubleClick` event.

I am trying to find out *which row exactly of the `DataGrid` was clicked*.

So far I've tried this:

```
private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow Row = sender as DataGridRow;
    int RowNumber = Row.GetIndex();
    //dostuff with RowNumber ;
}
```

which sadly gets me a `System.NullReferenceException`.

xaml for completeness:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_Table" Grid.Row="3" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True"
      MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" FontSize="22" />
```

Comment: You get null exception because it is the grid (DataGrid) sending the event and you try to convert/cast it to a `DataGridRow`. You probably want the `DataGrid.SelectedIndex` which would indicate the index of the `SelectedItem` or currently selected row of the grid. Note that that index is zero indexed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF datagrid selected row clicked event ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120616/wpf-datagrid-selected-row-clicked-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get null exception because it is the grid (DataGrid) sending the event and you try to convert/cast it to a `DataGridRow`. You probably want the `DataGrid.SelectedIndex` which would indicate the index of the `SelectedItem` or currently selected row of the grid. Note that that index is zero indexed.

```
private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dataGrid != null) {
        var index = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
        //dostuff with index
    }
}
```