# How to know when a DataGridRow is clicked?

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, windows-community-toolkit, winui-3

I am using [the Windows Community Toolkit WinUI DataGrid control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/communitytoolkit.winui.ui.controls.datagrid?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0). I would like to run some code when a row is clicked. How can I do that?

I have tried:

- `SelectionChanged` event: Only works the first time the row is clicked, as after that the same row is being selected. Also gets triggered if the row is moved to via the keyboard.
- `CurrentCellChanged` event: Only works the first time a cell is clicked, as after that clicking the same cell does not change the current cell. (And I could not find a way to clear the current cell programmatically.)
- [Answers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3120866/1438809) show how to add row event handlers via style in WPF, but this does not work in WinUI.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the `PointerReleased` event. (Previously I had discarded this event as I could not figure out which row was clicked.)

```xaml
<ctWinUI:DataGrid
    PointerReleased="dgDesktops_PointerReleased"
    ...>
```

And to find the `DataGridRow` that was clicked I traverse the visual tree:

```cs
private async void dgDesktops_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow clickedRow = ViewUtils.FindParent<DataGridRow>((UIElement)e.OriginalSource);
    if (clickedRow != null)
    {
        MyModel rowModel = (MyModel)clickedRow.DataContext;
        // Do stuff
    }
}

public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject childElement) where T : Control
{
    DependencyObject currentElement = childElement;

    while (currentElement != null)
    {
        if (currentElement is T matchingElement)
        {
            return matchingElement;
        }

        currentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currentElement);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works :)